# Should I use electron's webview to emulate a browser?

Tags: browser, electron

I want to write a browser for some purpose using electron and I choose the `<webview>` tag to emulate the browser page.
It has a toolbar which contains back forward refresh buttons.
I bind the `new window` event, in the handler I just create a new `<webview>` tag for that url.

However, I found that there are some limits.
1. window.opener in new `<webview>` is null
2. `<form>` with `method="POST"` can't be handled correctly, because there are no solutions to get postData from `new-window` event.(But there is probably a PR for this: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/19703)

Perhaps I'm wrong from the start. I shouldn't use electron for this purpose? But I don't know much about c#/c++...

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use `<webview>` at the moment as its usage is [strongly discouraged by the Electron team](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#warning). The recommendation is to use a `BrowserView` instead ([see documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view)).

Using Electron to build a web browser should work fine, there is actually a similar project called [Wexond](https://electronjs.org/apps/wexond). You could check it out as a starting point for your own browser.